Is it possible to get a chosen answer changed?
There's a question that was asked 4 years ago - this one - Can I cancel a transaction that has not been successfully broadcast yet?
The thing is, the chosen answer doesn't work well - as the comments later show, and also takes a long time, whereas the answer I gave isn't getting any visibility given it's way down and has zero votes.
This might not be the right place to ask this question, as perhaps it's more specific to the stackexchange platform than to the bitcoin stackexchange, but the question is - is it possible to flag an issue with the fact that the chosen answer might not be the best one?

i can't say if accepted answer can be changed (i doubt it), but i reviewed your answer and i suggested a small edit (in the word, but the substance is quite different), see if you can agree.

The asker is the only one that can accept or unaccept an answer to indicate which was most useful to them. You could:

Comment on the accepted answer to indicate that it is outdated and request that the answerer updates it
Downvote the accepted answer indicating that it is not useful
Suggest an edit to the accepted answer to introduce an update to make it useful
If it were really bad, flag and request that the accepted answer is deleted (which doesn't seem to fit this case)

According to their profiles, both the asker and answerer have visited this site in the past two months, so trying to engage with them may be fruitful.

The accepted answer can only be changed by the question asker. You will need to find a way to contact the user who asked that question and ask them to change the accepted answer.
